# XNA 4.0 and Effect Code

Tags: c#, xna, shader, xna-4.0, hlsl

I'm developing a game using XNA 4.0 library (not using game class and ContentManager)
As i known XNA 4.0 doesn't support compile effect at runtime.
I tried to compile .fx file with fxc compiler and load to Effect constructor like this code

```
FileStream f = new FileStream(FName, FileMode.Open);
byte[] fData = new byte[f.Length];
f.Read(fData, 0, FData.Length);
f.Close();
Effect ef = new Effect(GfxDev, fData);
```

I got exception error messages at this point
"You can only construct Effect with data that was already compiled. This data is not a compiled effect."

What the code i need to use for Effect constructor?
I checked MSDN and no explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output from `fxc` is subtly different to the output of the effect compiler in XNA. I cannot remember the exact details - but I believe that there are differences in the file header - something about enumerating the effect parameters, I think.

The solution, then, is to use the effect compiler that comes with XNA's content pipeline, in place of `fxc`. The class you need is `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Processors.EffectProcessor`.

Here is an example of how to use it. You can put this into a simple command-line project:

```
string fx = File.ReadAllText("Effect1.fx");

EffectProcessor effectProcessor = new EffectProcessor();
var effect = effectProcessor.Process(new EffectContent { EffectCode = fx }, new MyContext());

byte[] yourEffectCode = effect.GetEffectCode();
```

Note that you need a context class, derived from `ContentProcessorContext`. There are lots of methods you need to override, but only three are required to actually do anything for the above code to work:

```
class MyContext : ContentProcessorContext
{
    public override string BuildConfiguration { get { return ""; } }
    public override TargetPlatform TargetPlatform { get { return TargetPlatform.Windows; } }
    public override GraphicsProfile TargetProfile { get { return GraphicsProfile.HiDef; } }
    // ... other overrides ...
}
```

Note that (as well as `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll`) this requires that your project references `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.dll`. This requires that you project is built against the full .NET 4.0 framework (*not* the "Client Profile"). Also this content pipeline DLL is *not* redistributable (but then I'm not sure fxc is either).

Comment: So anyway i need to import and implements these Content pipeline  classes into my project.

Does it still working when i porting to Xbox 360 or Windows Phone ?


Thank you

Comment: The pipeline DLLs themselves don't work on those platforms. But the output from `EffectProcessor` will work if you set `TargetPlatform` to the correct value.